# In what role connects a BLE HID device to an iOS host?

Tags: ios, iphone, hid, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some confusion about connecting a HID device via Bluetooth Low Energy to an iOS host.

In its [Bluetooth design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf), Apple says:

> When third party iOS applications discover services on the accessory,
>   the following services are used internally by iOS and are filtered out
>   from the list of discovered services:
>
> - Generic Attribute Profile Service
> - Generic Access Profile Service
> - Bluetooth Low Energy HID Service
> - Apple Notification Center Service

So how do I connect something like a BLE keyboard to iOS? How would the BLE device, which is supposed to use the HID over GATT profile, announce its HID services to the iOS host?

If I understand the documentation correctly, iOS will **not** report a BLE HID service being announced from the accessory, so any software trying to connect will never find out that there is something which wants to communicate via HOGP. Which is the protocol for external keyboards and the like. Again, how can something like a BLE keyboard be recognized as a BLE HID service when iOS claims that functionality for itself?

Comment: You should be able to connect it through the iOS Settings Bluetooth screen

Comment: That is the answer.  The BLE device implements HID over GATT.  iOS detects HID over GATT devices in the settings.  I don't understand what else you are asking.

Comment: It can't. That is what I am saying. HID over GATT is managed by iOS. Apps have no access to these peripherals directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for that. Very helpful.